# Scalamock expect eventually

Tags: asynchronous, scalamock

I'm using `scalamock` to write a test. The problem is that action is asynchronous.
I have the following pseudo code

```
val resultCollectorMock = mock[ResultCollector]
(resultCollectorMock.collectResult _).expect(someResult)

val serviceUnderTest = new ServiceUnderTest(resultColletorMock)
serviceUnderTest.runAsyncJob(someParams)
```

This fails because the result is computed asynchronously, at time when the test ends, it's still not ready, so `collectResult` wasn't called, **yet**.

What I want to have is `expectEventually(value)(patienceConfig)` that is able to wait for some time for the method to be called.

I tried to use a `sutb` and `verify` instead, I wrapped it in `eventually` from `scalatest` but to no avail. For whatever reason `verify` seems to break the test at first evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `AsyncMockFactory` with an appropriate test suite and Futures as described in the docs at https://scalamock.org/user-guide/integration/

Comment: oh, now, I feel a bit embarrassed as I searched through spec I didn't notice it, perhaps I didn't expect to find it under `integration`. Anyway, it works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: I have a test which wont work with AsyncMockFactory. I have to use `eventually`, I'm surprised stub verification fails it without time backoffs.